# Clipping inverse drawing?

Tags: iphone, geometry, drawing, core-graphics, clipping

I'm want to remove the blue part of the following images. How do I clip the inverse of the drawing? (I believe that's the correct way to ask the question)

Example code for Triangle: (If there's better triangle code, I'd accept that too!;)

```
    int lineWidth = 4;

    int w = size.size.width;
    int h = size.size.height - lineWidth;

    CGPoint top = CGPointMake(0+(w/2)+.5, 0);

    CGContextClipToRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h));
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, top.x, top.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, top.x + (w/2), top.y + h  );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, top.x - (w/2), top.y + h   );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, top.x, top.y);

    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, top.x, top.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, top.x + (w/2), top.y + h  );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, top.x - (w/2), top.y + h   );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, top.x, top.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use UIBazierPath. Draw a Bazier Path according to your intentions. Then call [path addClip] method. It'll clip all the outside the closed path.
For example following code makes your view round cornered.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(6.0, 6.0)];
[path addClip];
```

Answer (score 0):

To clip the inverse of any path just add an enclosing rect to your clip.

In this case, if I get you right, you want to clip around the red stroke of the shapes. Generally, that's not an easy task in quartz due to the line width of the stroked path. Of course, for these two shapes, we can compute the outline of the red stroke and clip around that. But a general solution would need a way to calculate the encompassing path, including the line width.

There are other ways that include bitmap masks—but the best solution would depend on what exactly are you drawing. I just had a similar problem which I could very elegantly and efficiently solve using a specialized quartz blend mode. This depends very much on the contents of the centext before drawing and how the result should be blended with the rest of the UI.